# How can I resize my screen back to original?

Tags: javascript

```
const screen=player.querySelector('.resize');
const player= document.querySelector('.player');

screen.addEventListener('click',handlescreen);


function handlescreen(){
    player.requestFullscreen();
}
```

What exact code to write to resize my fullscreen to earlier one on clicking the same button?

Comment: Call `Document.exitFullScreen`?

Comment: [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen#examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [document.exitFullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/exitFullscreen)? In your method you could do:

```
function handlescreen() {
   if (this.fullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen()
        this.fullscreen = false
    } else {
        player.requestFullscreen()
        this.fullscreen = true
    }
}
```